# Angular 9: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, angular9

I am able to get data from the GET API in the service layer which is printed in  `console.log(data)` of ngOnInit() in list.ts file but I am unable to populate those values in HTML. While trying to populate the data in my HTML file, it throws the following error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'

Error

[image: Sample IMage]

Here is my code:

list.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private Service: service) { }
  lists:list[];
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.Service.getData()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.lists= data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

list.service.ts

```
  getData():Observable<any> {
    return this.httpclient.get("http://servername:8080/api/groups", {withCredentials: true});
   }
```

```
export class list{
    $id: string;
    Member: Member[];
    Name: string;
```

list.html

```
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Member</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
    
            <tr *ngFor="let a of lists">
                <td>{{ a.Member}}</td>
                <td>{{ a.Name}}</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: Could you please add the sample response you get as a part of console.log(data) as well here?

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran It something like this 

$id: "1"
Name"ABC"
Member(38) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}

Comment: sorry, im not sure how to make the result show properly in comments

Comment: @廖文俊EdwardLiew It looks likes Member is an array but list is an object.

Comment: not sure, Im also take some reference from internet learn the implementation get from api. Can you take a look on my list.ts whether I get the data in the correct way?

Comment: i check and see

Comment: oh ya inside is object

Comment: @廖文俊EdwardLiew - you can add the sample by editing the question details. However, I am not sure whether the ngFor will work properly as name is just a single value whereas members is an array of values.

Answer (score 1):

the error is saying that "data" is an object NOT an array.

either try this:

```
this.lists= [data];
```

or figure out why your data is not coming back as an array

Comment: just keep in mind, by using that syntax, you are forcing an object into an array of size 1, and you will never have more than 1 element in your array. meaning no reason to even use an array structure in your html.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is not array and you should convert your data to array or your data is string and you have to convert to json I take you some solostion for conver sting to json

number 1 :

```
this.lists= JSON.parse(data);
```

number 2 : you can map when you get data like this

```
     this.Service.getData()
        .map(data => data .json())
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.lists= data;
            console.log(data);
          });
```

Comment: is that i need to use something like JSON.stringify() in service once get from the api?